# Transform dataframe from coumns to row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which is a much longer version of this:

[Current Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOPx4.png)

From this I've been trying to turn it into this:

[Desired Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3D4R.png)

I've tried to create a dictionary using it but then had issues with remerging it to create the desired dataframe.

In all honesty I'm sure this is quite simple and I'm just missing it, any help would be truly appreciated.  I tried to post the data as text but had issues with it, really that's totally irrelevant I'm just confused about how to transform the data in the manner required.

Thank you again!

```
{1: {'Country': 'England', 'Subject Descriptor': 'Real GDP', '2011': '8,248.62', '2012': '8,835.39', '2013': '9,478.98', '2014': '10,224.38', '2015': '11,057.94', '2016': '11,477.97', nan: nan}, 2: {'Country': 'England', 'Subject Descriptor': 'Nom GDP', '2011': '15,158.02', '2012': '17,328.64', '2013': '19,758.15', '2014': '22,504.79', '2015': '25,424.83', '2016': '27,749.64', nan: nan}, 3: {'Country': 'England', 'Subject Descriptor': 'GDP defl', '2011': '183.764', '2012': '196.128', '2013': '208.442', '2014': '220.109', '2015': '229.924', '2016': '241.764', nan: nan}, 4: {'Country': 'Italy', 'Subject Descriptor': 'Real GDP', '2011': '56.524', '2012': '60.712', '2013': '64.55', '2014': '67.025', '2015': '69.893', '2016': '69.322', nan: nan}, 5: {'Country': 'Italy', 'Subject Descriptor': 'Nom GDP', '2011': '122.5', '2012': '136.911', '2013': '152.39', '2014': '163.456', '2015': '172.759', '2016': '178.37', nan: nan}, 6: {'Country': 'Italy', 'Subject Descriptor': 'GDP defl', '2011': '216.722', '2012': '225.509', '2013': '236.082', '2014': '243.873', '2015': '247.176', '2016': '257.306', nan: nan}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I think [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) would help you most. Here's a simple use of this functionality:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"Country": ["Subject", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"], "England": [
    "Norm GDP", "8,248.62", "8,835.39", "8,248.62", "8,835.39", "8,248.62"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df_t = df.transpose()
print(df_t)
```

Input:

```
   Country   England
0  Subject  Norm GDP
1     2010  8,248.62
2     2011  8,835.39
3     2012  8,248.62
4     2013  8,835.39
5     2014  8,248.62
```

Output:

```
                0         1         2         3         4         5
Country   Subject      2010      2011      2012      2013      2014
England  Norm GDP  8,248.62  8,835.39  8,248.62  8,835.39  8,248.62
```

You can simply ignore the dummy data I used. The most important is the function transpose. It is a mathematical technique that can be applied on matrices.

PS: Next time when posting questions, try to provide the datasets as text (instead of images), it's much easier for others to test their code then and you might receive help faster.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I've used that before but it doesn't provide the desired result.  What I want is to have it have the years going down and then repeating.  E.g. 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014.  I am grateful you took the time out to help.

Comment: @James ah, okay. If you could provide the whole dataset in text, it would be much easier to provide a correct solution.

Comment: Hello again, i added the dataset in text I got from python, I hope you can help me.  Thank you!